# How to add hashtags and cashtags with a link in the WordPress comments?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Ok, so I have managed to make it work for the_content, by adding this line in functions.php:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_hashcash_class');
function my_hashcash_class($content){   
    $content = preg_replace('/(\$|#)(\w+)[^\w".;]/s', '<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/?s=\2">\1\2</a> ', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

The above code works perfectly with the WordPress filter `the_content`

But when I'm trying to do the same for comments with `the_comments`, I'm getting an error:

```
There has been a critical error on this website.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.
```

Comments are not even displayed.

Here's my comments code:

```
add_filter('the_comments', 'my_hashcash_comments_class');
function my_hashcash_comments_class($comments){
    $comments = preg_replace('/(\$|#)(\w+)[^\w".;]/s', '<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/?s=\2">\1\2</a> ', $comments);
    return $comments;
}
```

Maybe WordPress is trying to apply the filter for commenter user name, avatar, and all that other stuff.

I want the filter to be applied only to the comment content itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Please share that the_comments code as well.

Comment: updated with the_comments code.

Comment: Seeing the plural word `$comments` I am wondering if it is an array instead of a string? [the_comments()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_comments/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code. the "$comments" parameter is an array object of WP_Comment Object so you have access by loop.

```
add_filter('the_comments', 'my_hashcash_comments_class');
function my_hashcash_comments_class($comments){
    foreach ( $comments  as $key => $comment ) {
        $comments[$key]->comment_content = preg_replace( '/(\$|#)(\w+)[^\w".;]/s', '<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/?s=\2">\1\2</a>', $comment->comment_content );
    }
    return $comments;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not WP, but judging my Bhautik's answer, you are dealing with an array of objects.  Because objects remain mutable in a loop, you can apply the change directly to the object without referring to it by its key.

Your regex pattern could do with some refinement.  When matching a literal `$` and `#`, just put them in a character class and avoid the piping and escaping.

The `\w+` is appropriate, but the following negated character class is not necessary.  In fact, it will cause your pattern to fail if the very last character in the string are still the `\w` of the hash/cash substring.

The `s` pattern modifier is only of any value if you have a non-literal `.` in your pattern.  You do not, so there is no use to the pattern modifier -- omit it.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/W73hn))

```
$comments = [
    (object)['comment_content' => 'Hello $there fella'],
    (object)['comment_content' => 'Hashy #tag123 text']
];

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    $comment->comment_content = preg_replace(
        '~[$#](\w+)~',
        '<a href="https://www.example.com/?s=\1">\0</a>',
        $comment->comment_content
    );
}
var_export($comments);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'comment_content' => 'Hello <a href="https://www.example.com/?s=there">$there</a> fella',
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'comment_content' => 'Hashy <a href="https://www.example.com/?s=tag123">#tag123</a> text',
  ),
)
```